# QML Row "fill" / auto-spacing?

Tags: qt, qml

Instead of assigning a fixed `spacing` between items, it is possible to evenly spread the items along the (parent's) `width`, so as to maximize spacing?

What I currently do is:

```
Row {
    width: parent.width
    readonly property real childrenWidth: {
        var w = 0
        for(var child of children) w += child.width
        return w
    }
    spacing: (width - childrenWidth) / Math.max(1, children.length - 1)
    MyElement {}
    MyElement {}
    ...
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `RowLayout`

```
RowLayout {
    width: parent.width

    MyElement { Layout.fillWidth: true }
    MyElement { Layout.fillWidth: true }
}
```

If needed you can declare `minimumWidth`, `preferredWidth` and/or `maximumWidth`, see the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html). Without these, the `implicitWidth` of `MyElement` is used.

Comment: The question is about auto-spacing, not auto-sizing items.